# How do I use regex to remove substring before a pipe in pandas dataframe?

Tags: regex, pandas

In `cna` pandas dataframe, for all values of `Hugo_symbol` column, if there is a pipe (`|`) followed by "ENSG*", remove everything before the pipe.

My code:

```
import re
cna["Hugo_Symbol"] = [re.sub(r"^\|.*", "", str(x)) for x in cna["Hugo_Symbol"]]
```

Current `cna` dataframe

|  | Hugo_Symbol | TCGA_1 | TCGA_2 | TCGA_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GENEID|ENSG12345 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 1 | GENEA | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 |
| 2 | ANOTHERGENEID|ENSG6789 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 |
| 3 | GENEB | 1.0 | 1.1 | 1.2 |

Desired output

|  | Hugo_Symbol | TCGA_1 | TCGA_2 | TCGA_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ENSG12345 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 1 | GENEA | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 |
| 2 | ENSG6789 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 |
| 3 | GENEB | 1.0 | 1.1 | 1.2 |

Comment: Why don't you check for `ENSG` after the pipe in your regular expression? Isn't that part of the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```py
cna["Hugo_Symbol"] = cna["Hugo_Symbol"].str.replace(r'^[^|]*\|', '', regex=True)
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
- `\|` -  a `|` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i9cKPA/1).

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
cna = pd.DataFrame({'Hugo_Symbol':['GENEID|ENSG12345', 'GENEA'], 'TCGA_1':[0.1, 0.4]})
cna["Hugo_Symbol"].str.replace(r'^[^|]*\|', '', regex=True)
0    ENSG12345
1        GENEA
Name: Hugo_Symbol, dtype: object
```

**NOTE on `regex=True`**:

Acc. to [Pandas 1.2.0 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecationse):

> The default value of *regex* for [`Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) will change from *True* to *False* in a future release. In addition, single character regular expressions will not be treated as literal strings when *regex=True* is set ([GH24804](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24804)).

Comment: Any advantage in using `[^|]*\|` in place of `.*\|`? As you need to match the `\|` anyway I don't see how this could have an impact.

Comment: @mozway `.*\|` will match as many chars other than line break chars as possible up to the last occurrence of a `|` char. In the cases above, removing up to first (leftmost) `|` is enough, and the pattern based on a negated character class is the most efficient here. You can compare the step # needed by [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/i9cKPA/2)  vs. [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/i9cKPA/3).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple regex wth [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
cna['Hugo_Symbol'] = cna['Hugo_Symbol'].str.replace(r'^(.*\|)', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
  Hugo_Symbol  TCGA_1  TCGA_2  TCGA_3
0   ENSG12345     0.1     0.2     0.3
1       GENEA     0.4     0.5     0.6
2    ENSG6789     0.7     0.8     0.9
3       GENEB     1.0     1.1     1.2
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMKiMc/1)